# Magento How to add custom field into Role Creation Form and save its value into database

Tags: magento

[image]I have a requirement to add an extra field on to the Role Creation form.

I was able to do by 2 ways
 - Using Event Observer
 - Or by rewriting blocks

But I want to save this field into the data base and want to populate this value on edit role page.

I tried -

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('navigator_information', array(
            'legend' => 'Navigator Information',
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
                )
          );

      $options = array();
      $options['client'] = 'client'; 
      $options['report'] = 'report';

          //add new field
          $fieldset->addField('navigator_role', 'select',
            array(
                'name'  => 'navigator_role',
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Navigator Roles'),
                'id'    => 'navigator_role',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
        'values' => $options,
                'required' => true,
              )
          );
```

and it shows me the new fieldset and new field but How to store this value
into db?

Any help would be appreciated.

I have uploaded screen shot that shows new field